# messed up screen sharing

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, screen-sharing

I am screen sharing from an iMac 10.6.8 looking at a MacBook Pro 10.8. Quite often, but not always, the shared screen looks like this on my iMac.

[image]

(This image is anonymized.) So there is the real shared screen down below, and an inverted piece of it at top. Neither piece is active, in that I can't do anything on them remotely. What's going on? Is a display setting messed up on one machine? Help! This is really annoying. I can easily do screen sharing to other machines.